# How should I proceed and what precautions should I take to work with a non-licensed electrician who hasn't given me a contract (in California)?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I had a highly rated electrician from a reputable online contractor listing quote a subpanel upgrade. He is not licensed. (He’s been in business for probably 25 years) I asked him why he’s not licensed and he says that electricians are not required to be licensed.  (He's also not insured or bonded)

He seems really knowledgeable when I asked him questions and we always prompt with his responses.

Another question is that I’ve asked him a few times to provide a quote and/or contract in writing and he still hasn’t provided something and he’s going to start work in a few days.

Is that a red flag or is it okay to proceed with work? If so, what precautions should I take?  He says this is a subpanel upgrade and doesn't need to be permitted.  I'm okay with this b/c when we bought the house the garage (where the subpanel is) was not really up to code. If I were to permit and an inspector shows up, they would probably have me upgrade all of the electrical in the garage.

(Note: I didn't want to list any websites, but the online listing is the popular one with a person's name as the name of the website :) )

Comment: It can be legal for a friend to help you without pay.  In most places it will be almost or illegal to be paid for electrical work if not licensed.  Your insurance can be denied also.  Maybe he does not want to pay for his licence anymore or it was taken away.

Comment: This question is likely to get closed because it's asking for opinions.  I suggest you rewrite it so that it can be answered objectively.  You might ask for example what the regulatory  requirements are in CA for someone to do electrical work for pay.  IMO if *you* thoroughly know what you're doing (and thus have had some training or experience yourself) and you hire an extra pair of hands, that is "okay" but if you are relying on this person to know more than you or to take full responsibility for doing the job right, it is not okay.

Comment: Do NOT let him start work without a contract.

Comment: He can be a highly rated handyman and be unlicensed, but for him to do a job exceeding $500 is illegal. Run! There are very few upsides to this arrangement.

Comment: I smell an XY problem. What's the underlying purpose? If it's EV charging, let's talk.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica.  You're hunch is spot on...

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  I cancelled the project with him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This will end badly

The "licensing" requirement can be bit ungainly, and could unjustly exclude a competent person.  Sure. However: **A competent person will have everything else absolutely tip top:** Insurance. Permits. Plan of work written down and agreed. Quote made in writing.

To shank *all of those at once*? **No.**  That person is not competent, they are scamming you. They are a smooth talker who is good at "reading people" and saying what gets under your skin in the most persuasive way.  If you're too vain to think you are subject to manipulation, well, that's part of the con.  If they were competent *at electrical*, they would position themselves as an "extra hand" subcontractor working under the permits, supervision and insurance of a licensed electrician.

I would rather see you DIY this thing than involve this operator.

And stop calling the person an "electrician".

### Solving your problem, though.

> He says this is a subpanel upgrade and doesn't need to be permitted.

Really? Contact your AHJ and ask them about that.  If they ask for an address, give one across town.

> If I were to permit and an inspector shows up, they would probably have me upgrade all of the electrical in the garage.

That's **naysaying**.  They can't even do that legally; past work is *grandfathered* unless it was illegal at the time of installation.

When you have an obsolete/dangerous panel like Zinsco, FPE or Pushmatic (nothing *wrong* with Pushmatic; it's excellent just obsolete)... the AHJ wants to prioritize that replacement, so they won't burden your project by throwing additional work into scope. You are welcome to seize the opportunity to also select a panel with many more *spaces* - enough to ensure you never run out, which is our recommendation.

If you want to also enlarge the feeder, that is another kettle of fish, because people do that to accommodate additional loads, and that requires a Load Calculation and the AHJ will want a permit there so they can review that.  So consider *not* enlarging the feeder in this phase of the project.

Now if your root goal is to provide 50A or 60A to charge an EV, we can help with that in a way that doesn't require a feeder upgrade most likely.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking a few red flags. The main one is not bonded or insured. He does the work and your house burns down, your homeowner's insurance won't cover you.  You should demand a contract and don't let him start without one. He can change the rules down the road and you have no recourse. Lastly, I'm pretty sure you need to be licensed in California if you're working for/ charging someone for work. Also, I'd be cautious of any "reputable" online listings.

Comment: I would get someone who is appropriately licenced. You are liable for everything that goes wrong. I do not know about your homeowners insurance but mine would not cover. I had an incident a few years back and they went to the city to verify that the work had been permitted. I asked what if they could not find it and was told it would be my expense unless I could prove it was inspected and approved.

Comment: Re: permitting and homeowners insurance...I'm pretty sure that none of the electrical work in the garage was permitted or to code (from when we bought the house).  So maybe homeowners insurance should not be a concern?

Comment: @milesmeow  Just because insurance did not catch it at the time, you can be sure they will check if the house burns down.  They like taking your money, but hate giving it back.